# Atribuir um valor do array e uma variável

Tags: array, flutter, dart

Estou precisando atribuir um valor de uma lista dentro de uma variável, porém não sei como chamar ela pra dentro da função.

```
void calcula() {

setState(() {
   double tensaoValue = double.tryParse(tensaoController.text);

  double wattsValue = double.tryParse(wattsController.text);
  double distanciaValue = double.tryParse(distanciaController.text);
 

  
 kva = wattsValue * fp;

 correnteValue =  (raiz * tensaoValue* cos)/kva;

  if(correnteValue  <=30){
   resistenciaValue =    //valor lista[0]
   }else if (correnteValue >30 && correnteValue<=40){
   resistenciaValue = ; //lista[1]
   }else if(correnteValue >40 && correnteValue<=55){
   resistenciaValue = ; //lista[2]
  }else if(correnteValue >55 && correnteValue <=70){
   resistenciaValue =;//lista[3]
  }else if(correnteValue >70 && correnteValue <=100){
   resistenciaValue = ; //lista[4]
   }else if (correnteValue >100 && correnteValue <=130){
  resistenciaValue = ;//lista[5]
  }else if(correnteValue >130 && correnteValue<=175){
   resistenciaValue = ;//lista[6]
 }else if (correnteValue >175 && correnteValue <=275){
  resistenciaValue = ;//lista[7]
 }



});}

    void tabela(){
      var lista = new List();
      lista[0]=8.57;
      lista[1]=5.38;
      lista[2]=3.39;
      lista[3]=2.13;
      lista[4]=1.34;
      lista[5]=0.84;
      lista[6]=0.53;
      lista[7]=0.33;
      lista[8]=0.26;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Se eu compreendi bem, você quer usar a `var lista` dentro da função `void calcula()`. Eu não compreendi o sentido de criar uma função chamada tabela para por a lista dentro. Uma alternativa seria colocar a lista dentro da função `calcula()` ou inicializar ela dentro da classe, caso precise ser acessada por outras funções.

```
void calcula() {

final List<double> lista = [8.57, 5.38, 3.39, 2.13, 1.34, 0.84, 0.53, 0.33, 0.26];

setState(() {
   double tensaoValue = double.tryParse(tensaoController.text);

  double wattsValue = double.tryParse(wattsController.text);
  double distanciaValue = double.tryParse(distanciaController.text);
 

  
 kva = wattsValue * fp;

 correnteValue =  (raiz * tensaoValue* cos)/kva;

  if(correnteValue  <=30){
   resistenciaValue =  lista[0];
   }else if (correnteValue >30 && correnteValue<=40){
   resistenciaValue = lista[1];
   }else if(correnteValue >40 && correnteValue<=55){
   resistenciaValue = lista[2];
  }else if(correnteValue >55 && correnteValue <=70){
   resistenciaValue = lista[3];
  }else if(correnteValue >70 && correnteValue <=100){
   resistenciaValue = lista[4];
   }else if (correnteValue >100 && correnteValue <=130){
  resistenciaValue = lista[5];
  }else if(correnteValue >130 && correnteValue<=175){
   resistenciaValue = lista[6];
 }else if (correnteValue >175 && correnteValue <=275){
  resistenciaValue = lista[7];
 }



});}
```